# Knockout Complex variables not binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have made a jsfiddle with my code at
http://jsfiddle.net/dorraba/HuDPJ/
I want to create a simple shopping cart where I can add and remove Items.
My intention is that the Product will be an object (Name and Price)
The Shopping cart will hold a list of items, where each item is built from a Product and quantity.

My problem is I can't find a way to set the textbox Price by the product selected in the dropdown list in each line.

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you should use the value binding for input elements, otherwise you will get a DOM error.
 
Furthermore you have set the `optionsValue` property of the options binding to `'Name'`, which will cause knockout to set the value of `ShoppingCartItem.Product` to the name of the product.

Binding to  nested properties like `Product.Price` will cause an error if a parent (in this case `Price`) evaluates to undefined. 
Hence you need to test if Product is defined... like this: `data-bind="value: (Product() ? Product().Price : '')"`

Here is a working solution of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HuDPJ/1/